# nodejs Eclipse debugger: how to specify arguments?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging, nodeclipse

I need to launch the Eclipse nodejs debugger with the specification of an argument.
Launching the nodejs application from the commmand line is done as follows:

```
node myApp.js argumentValue
```

The value of the argument is then accessible inside the app by using the following:

```
process.argv[1]
```

I don't know how to add the argument value when launching the application through Eclipse debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to be the modification of my nodejs app debug configuration.
In Eclipse choose from the menu **Run>Debug Configurations** then choose the application script under the Node Application block, you should see:

[image: debug configuration area]

Now select the Arguments tab:

[image: Arguments tab]

Insert the value of the argument and press Apply.