# Proxy is not defined when I try to compile a .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, proxy

I am a Windows users, and I am using eclipse to compile my .js file.(I have the Node.js on my system). The assignment that my professor gave to us is about using proxy. I tried to run the example:

```
var incompleteHandler = {get:function(myProxy, name){
   console.log('Property ' + name + ' accessed.');
   return 1;}};
var p = Proxy.create(incompleteHandler);
var q = p.hello;
```

It gives me a error says Proxy is not defined.
My professor is a Mac user. He did mention about a command "$node --harmony-proxies prog.js" in order to use Proxy. But I do not know how to apply this command. Anyone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Over here you will find information how to setup run params in eclipse -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882928/nodejs-eclipse-debugger-how-to-specify-arguments . Just put --harmony-proxies in node arguments section

Comment: Hi Damian, thank you for answering my question. I did what you showed to me, the old question has solved. But new problem ''Cannot find module '' occurs. Do you have any idea about this?